# HTML: How to duplicate footer across all pages without PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, footer

Looking for advise on whether is it possible to have a footer.html and duplicate it to all pages without using PHP.

I know I can use include("footer.php"), but all my pages are in HTML now and I will have to change all css paths.

I read up [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) on how to use w3-include-html & javascript. However I realize the javascript is lagging every pages, making page loading longer.

Is there any other option?

```
<body>
<script>
    function includeHTML() {
      var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
      /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
      z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
          /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
              if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
              /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
              elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
              includeHTML();
            }
          }
          xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
          xhttp.send();
          /* Exit the function: */
          return;
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>

<script>
    includeHTML();
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're asking for a solution _without_ PHP, you can remove that tag and rephrase it as "include footer on all pages with JS only". No need to mention any specific backend language at all.

Comment: _"I know I can use include("footer.php"), but all my pages are in HTML now and I will have to change all css paths."_ - why, what's the CSS got to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could think different, but I don't know if it is, what you want, because the architecture of your application will grow up / become a littlebit ugly.

You define a php-script, that is loading your static html and appends the php-code you want. Then you need a rewrite rule, to get the script as the center of your tiny html-universe ;-)

An example, that should work on an apache with rewrite-mod enabled.

Mention, that you create this directory-structure on your server:

- .../.htaccess
- .../index.php  <<< this renders the "header", content of your html-files and last footer
- .../html-pages <<< place your files here

Place an .htaccess in the root-folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" !^.*/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(?!.*index\.php)(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Place an index.php in the samefolder:

```
<?php
... here could be your header-code

define ('PAGES_DIR', __DIR__ . '/html-pages')
define ('DEFAULT_PAGE', 'index.html')

// we need to handle virtual pathes
$requestPath = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    $requestPath = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) && strpos($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'], basename(__FILE__)) === FALSE) {
    $requestPath = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
}
if ($requestPath == '/' || strlen(trim($requestPath)) == 0 || strlen(trim($requestPath)) == basename(__FILE__)) {
    $requestPath = DEFAULT_PAGE;
}

// this sends the content of your file to the browser
@readfile(PAGES_DIR . "/$requestPath");

... now your footer-code
```

And your html-files needs be placed into the "html-pages"-folder.

If you have done, your server should handle http://domain.tld/bla-fasel-blub.html as followed:

1. redirect the not existing path to index.php
   RewriteRule ^(?!.*index.php)(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
2. render the header
3. read the requested html-file (the $1 of the RewriteRule will be "bla-fasel-blub.html" and becomes value of "$requestPath") and send the content to the browser
4. render the rest of index.php (the footer or whatever)

I hope it helps, generating an idea for your problem.